# how to find series of a numbers those have 5 or more factors in a given range in c++

Tags: c++, factors

#include 
    using namespace std;

```
int main()
{
    int n, i;

    cout << "Enter a positive integer: ";
    cin >> n;

    cout << "Factors of " << n << " are: " << endl;  
    for(i = 1; i <= n; ++i)
    {
        if(n % i == 0)
            cout << i << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

**I understand the below problem of finding factors of numbers. But i want to do a c++ program which only show the numbers which have 5 or more factors. suppose i give a range of numbers 15 to 20.then it will print only those numbers those have 5 or more factors. such as example if i give a range 15 to 20 then it will print out only 16,18,20.because these 3 integers have 5 or more factors in 15 to 20 range. i couldnt understand how to do that code so i am asking.**

Comment: Can you please add some more detail/sample case?  As is it is unclear what you are asking.

Comment: Want to know about prime factors ?

Comment: "how to find series of a numbers those have 5 or more factors in a given range in c++." Which ones are to be in the range? The factors or the numbers themselves?

Comment: @Adrian Colomitchi    

i want to say that i will give a range of numbers as a input and i print only those numbers which has 5 or more factors

Answer (score 1):

As I understood you are searching the tech finding number prime factors of an natural number. Firstly the code you published is for getting all the divisor's of given positive number. But Finding its prime factors a little bit different but the idea same as you used (modular arithmetic)

this is a very simple version of achieving your task (but needs optimization)

```
#include <iostream>

//This function does not handle the repeating factors count
int numberOfPrimeFactors(int number) {
    int count = 0;

    for ( int i = 2; i <= number; ++i ) {
        while ( number % i == 0 ) {
            number /= i;
            count++;
        }
    }
    return count;
}


int main() {

    int Rbegin = 1;
    int Rend   = 100;

    for(int i = Rbegin; i<Rend; ++i) {
        if(numberOfPrimeFactors(i) >= 5)
            std::cout << i << " has 5 or more prime factor"<< std::endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: No
 i want to say that i will give a range of numbers as a input and  print  it only those numbers which has 5 or more factors .Hope you understand

Comment: @RashedSami he's almost doing that. Just put there input of range, and fix output formatting any way you wish. Hope you can write basic C++ code?

Comment: @Cherkesgiller Tural
[Link](http://imgur.com/a/lSShe)
you can see your program shows the output of  those prime factors but i want to know print the numbers   those have 5 or more factors>

Comment: Output of program which you link it , is not a prime factors but numbers whose prime factor count is greater or equal to 5. Please explain your problem more detail. I did not understand what you mean.

Comment: @ Cherkesgiller Tural 
suppose i  give a range of numbers 15 to 20.then it will print only those numbers those have 5 or more factors. such as example if i give a range 15 to 20 then it will print out only 16,18,20.because these 3 have  5 or more factors in 15 to 20 range.
i couldnt understand how to do that so i am asking 
Hope you Understand..